# Ruby loop over the dates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, loops

Hello I have Schedules table like this;

```
<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Schedule id: 427, date: "2016-06-15", notes: nil, price: "350", promo: "", status: "available", boat_id: 45, created_at: "2016-06-09 19:43:15", updated_at: "2016-06-09 19:43:15">, #<Schedule id: 428, date: "2016-06-16", notes: nil, price: "350", promo: "", status: "available", boat_id: 45, created_at: "2016-06-09 19:43:15", updated_at: "2016-06-09 19:43:15">, #<Schedule id: 429, date: "2016-06-17", notes: nil, price: "350", promo: "", status: "available", boat_id: 45, created_at: "2016-06-09 19:43:15", updated_at: "2016-06-09 19:43:15">, #<Schedule id: 430, date: "2016-06-22", notes: "", price: "253", promo: "", status: "available", boat_id: 3, created_at: "2016-06-14 09:23:55", updated_at: "2016-06-14 09:23:55">, #<Schedule id: 431, date: "2016-06-23", notes: "", price: "253", promo: "", status: "available", boat_id: 3, created_at: "2016-06-14 09:23:55", updated_at: "2016-06-14 09:23:55">]
```

and user inputs "from" and "to" dates. Lets say I have variables such

```
a = "2016-06-16".in_time_zone('UTC')
b = "2016-06-19".in_time_zone('UTC')
```

I would like to loop over Schedule table between these dates (a and b) and get the sum of prices..

I think of a such solution that, I can say;

```
a = "2016-06-16".in_time_zone('UTC')
b = "2016-06-19".in_time_zone('UTC')
schedules = Schedule.all
price = 0

dates = []
while a < b do
 dates << a
 a += 1.day
end
```

Then;

```
dates.each do |date|
  schedules.each do |schedule|
    if (date == schedule.in_time_zone('UTC'))
      price += schedule.price.to_i
    end
  end
end
```

but do not know if that is the most convenient way to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not taking the advantage of DB native implementations. You can do it in SQL.

```
date_from = "2016-06-16".in_time_zone('UTC')
date_to   = "2016-06-19".in_time_zone('UTC')

Schedule
  .where(date: date_from..date_to) # sql BETWEEN operator
  .sum("price") # SQL aggregate function.
```

Comment: You can pass a range to `where`?? That's AWESOME.

Comment: @maxhm10 You can. Look [Range Conditions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#hash-conditions) .